# Python: how can I handle any unhandled exception in an alternative way?

Tags: python, exception

Normally unhandled exceptions go to the stdout (or stderr?), I am building an app where I want to pass this info to the GUI before shutting down and display it to the user and, at the same time I want to write it to a log file. So, I need an str with the full text of the exception.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 23):

Use sys.excepthook to replace the base exception handler.  You can do something like:

```
import sys
from PyQt4 import QtGui

import os.path
import traceback

def handle_exception(exc_type, exc_value, exc_traceback):
  """ handle all exceptions """

  ## KeyboardInterrupt is a special case.
  ## We don't raise the error dialog when it occurs.
  if issubclass(exc_type, KeyboardInterrupt):
    if QtGui.qApp:
      QtGui.qApp.quit()
    return

  filename, line, dummy, dummy = traceback.extract_tb( exc_traceback ).pop()
  filename = os.path.basename( filename )
  error    = "%s: %s" % ( exc_type.__name__, exc_value )

  QtGui.QMessageBox.critical(None,"Error",
    "<html>A critical error has occured.<br/> "
  + "<b>%s</b><br/><br/>" % error
  + "It occurred at <b>line %d</b> of file <b>%s</b>.<br/>" % (line, filename)
  + "</html>")

  print "Closed due to an error. This is the full error report:"
  print
  print "".join(traceback.format_exception(exc_type, exc_value, exc_traceback))
  sys.exit(1)



# install handler for exceptions
sys.excepthook = handle_exception
```

This catches all unhandled exceptions, so you don't need a try...except block at the top level of your code.

Comment: It caches all unhandled exceptions in the main thread, but if you use the threading module, threading.Thread has its own try/except handler which circumvents sys.excepthook. See http://bugs.python.org/issue1230540.

Comment: this is very useful now i can handle all exceptions and send those exceptions to server

Answer (score 11):

You already got excellent answers, I just wanted to add one more tip that's served me well over the years in a variety of language for the specific problem "how to cleanly diagnose, log, etc, `out of memory` errors?".  Problem is, if your code gets control before enough objects have been destroyed and their memory recycled, memory might be too tight to do propert logging, gui work, etc, etc -- how do we ensure this doesn't happen?

Answer: build an emergency stash so you know you can spend it in such emergencies:

```
rainydayfund = [[] for x in xrange(16*1024)]  # or however much you need

def handle_exception(e):
  global rainydayfund
  del rainydayfund
  ... etc, etc ...
```

Answer (score 1):

I tried using [Neil's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1235434/4794), but it doesn't work with a Tkinter GUI. For that, I had to [override `report_callback_exception()`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4771200/4794).

```
import Tkinter as tk
import tkMessageBox
import traceback

class MyApp(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, *args, **kwargs):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent, *args, **kwargs)
        parent.report_callback_exception = self.report_callback_exception
        self.parent = parent
        self.button_frame = tk.Frame(self)
        self.button_frame.pack(side='top')
        self.button_run = tk.Button(
            self.button_frame, text="Run", command=self.run
        )
        self.button_run.grid(row=0, column=1, sticky='W')

    def run(self):
        tkMessageBox.showinfo('Info', 'The process is running.')
        raise RuntimeError('Tripped.')

    def report_callback_exception(self, exc_type, exc_value, exc_traceback):
        message = ''.join(traceback.format_exception(exc_type,
                                                     exc_value,
                                                     exc_traceback))
        tkMessageBox.showerror('Error', message)

def main():
    root = tk.Tk()  # parent widget

    MyApp(root).pack(fill='both', expand=True)

    root.mainloop()  # enter Tk event loop

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Answer (score 0):

```
try:
    # blah blah The Main Loop, function, whatever...
except e:
    do_something_with(str(e))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import sys, logging

logging.basicConfig(filename='/path/to/log/file', filemode='w')    
...

try:
   your_code_here()
except:
   logging.exception("My code failed") # logs exception to file
   # you define display_exception_in_ui as "def display_exception_in_ui(exc, tb):"
   display_exception_in_ui(*sys.exc_info()[1:]) # passes exception instance, traceback
```