# How can I make silent exceptions louder in tkinter?

Tags: python, exception, user-interface, tkinter, warnings

If I run the following code from a terminal, I get a helpful error message in the terminal:

```
import Tkinter as tk

master = tk.Tk()

def callback():
    raise UserWarning("Exception!")

b = tk.Button(master, text="This will raise an exception", command=callback)
b.pack()

tk.mainloop()
```

However, if I run it without a terminal (say, by double-clicking an icon), the error message is suppressed.

In my real, more complicated Tkinter application, I like that the GUI is a little crash-resistant. I don't like that my users have a hard time giving me useful feedback to fix the resulting unexpected behavior.

How should I handle this? Is there a standard way to expose tracebacks or stderror or whatnot in a Tkinter application? I'm looking for something more elegant than putting try/except everywhere.

EDIT: Jochen Ritzel gave an excellent answer below that pops up a warning box, and mentioned attaching it to a class. Just to make this explicit:

```
import Tkinter as tk
import traceback, tkMessageBox

class App:
    def __init__(self, master):
        master.report_callback_exception = self.report_callback_exception
        self.frame = tk.Frame(master)
        self.frame.pack()
        b = tk.Button(
            self.frame, text="This will cause an exception",
            command=self.cause_exception)
        b.pack()

    def cause_exception(self):
        a = []
        a.a = 0 #A traceback makes this easy to catch and fix

    def report_callback_exception(self, *args):
        err = traceback.format_exception(*args)
        tkMessageBox.showerror('Exception', err)

root = tk.Tk()
app = App(root)
root.mainloop()
```

My remaining confusion: Jochen mentions the possibility of having different exception reporting functions in different frames. I don't yet see how to do that. Is this obvious?

Comment: The exception is still output when you double click the icon. It's just that you're not printing standard out anywhere.

Comment: Agreed! I'm looking for people to recommend an elegant/standard way to expose stdout or stderror to the user.

Comment: The class `App` is a frame, usually derived from `tk.Frame`. If your program had two different frame classes that were used for different things, then each frame class could have its own version of `report_callback_exception()` that displays the error in a different way.

Comment: In python 3, `tkMessageBox` has moved to `tkinter.messagebox`, so
`import tkinter.messagebox` then in the body of `report_callback` `tkinter.messagebox.showerror(...)`.

Answer (score 41, accepted):

There is `report_callback_exception` to do this:

```
import traceback
import tkMessageBox  # py3: import tkinter.messagebox as tkMessageBox

# You would normally put that on the App class
def show_error(self, *args):
    err = traceback.format_exception(*args)
    tkMessageBox.showerror('Exception',err)
# but this works too
tk.Tk.report_callback_exception = show_error
```

If you didn't `import Tkinter as tk`, then do

```
Tkinter.Tk.report_callback_exception = show_error
```

Comment: Excellent, thank you! Would you mind expanding on your comment about putting that on the App class?

Comment: @Andrew: I just meant that usually you would write your application in a subclass that overwrites this method, instead of changing the Tk class itself. Just in case you want different report functions in different frames.

Comment: Related: [Handling exception in python tkinter](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35073005/3357935)

Comment: If you have an App class for `Tk`, you can override the error handling function with `def report_callback_exception(self, exc, val, tb): tkMessageBox.showerror("Exception", message=str(val))`

Comment: Also works in python3, but you need to use `messagebox` from `tkinter` module instead of `tkMessageBox`.

Answer (score 3):

First a followup: Just today, a patch on the [CPython tracker](http://bugs.python.org/issue22384) for the `tkinter.Tk.report_callback_exception` docstring made it clear that [Jochen's solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4771200/3357935) is intended.  The patch also (and primarily) stopped tk from crashing on callback exceptions when run under pythonw on Windows.

Second: here is a bare-bones beginning of a solution to making `stderr` function with no console (this should really be a separate SO question).

```
import sys, tkinter

root = tkinter.Tk()

class Stderr(tkinter.Toplevel):
    def __init__(self):
        self.txt = tkinter.Text(root)
        self.txt.pack()
    def write(self, s):
        self.txt.insert('insert', s)

sys.stderr = Stderr()

1/0 # traceback appears in window
```

More is needed to keep the popup window hidden until needed and then make it visible.

Answer (score 1):

Just too add more value in @Jochen Ritzel's answer, You `try except` from beginning of your program to catch the python error too.

for example to detect `index out of range` error of for loop, you can use:

```
# Note import files before the try statement

from tkinter import *
from tkinter import messagebox 
import sys,traceback
def show_error(slef, *args):
    err = traceback.format_exception(*args)
    messagebox.showerror('Exception',err)
try:
    root=Tk()
    Tk.report_callback_exception = show_error
    a=[1,2,3]
    for i in range(10):
        print(a[i])
    exec(input()) # Just used to throw error
    a=Button(text='s',command=lambda: print(8/0)) # Just used to throw error
    a.pack()
    root.mainloop()
except BaseException as e:
    messagebox.showerror('Exception',e)
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's my 2 cents — cut and paste code that will display a dialog whether or not it occurred when `tkinter` was executing a callback function.

```
import sys
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter.messagebox import showerror
import traceback


def excepthook(exctype, excvalue, tb):
    """Display exception in a dialog box."""
    msg = ('An uncaught exception has occurred!\n\n'
           + '\n'.join(traceback.format_exception(exctype, excvalue, tb))
           + '\nTerminating.')
    showerror('Error!', msg)
    sys.exit()

sys.excepthook = excepthook  # Replace default system exception hook.


class MyTk(tk.Tk):
    """Tk subclass with callback exception reporting method that displays the
    exception is a dialog box.
    """
    def report_callback_exception(self, exctype, excvalue, tb):
        excepthook(exctype, excvalue, tb)


def raise_exception():
    """Callback function."""
    x = 1 / 0

def main():
    root = MyTk()
#    y = 1 / 0  # Uncomment to test exception handling in non-callback functions.
    tk.Button(root, text='Do something', command=raise_exception).pack()
    root.mainloop()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Answer (score 0):

I found this thread while looking to solve the same problem. I had to make some modifications based on current `tkinter` version methodologies. I also added a customized error message handler since I figured my user wouldn't know what the Tk error message meant.

In the `__init__` of your class include:

`parent.report_callback_exception = self.report_callback_exception`

then in your Tk class:

```
    def report_callback_exception(self, exc, val, tb):
        #Handles tkinter exceptions
        err_msg = {'Index 0 out of range': 'None found'}
        try:
            err = err_msg[str(val)]
        except KeyError:
            err = 'Oops, try again'
        messagebox.showerror('Error Found', err)
```

You could expand the `err_msg` dictionary to include whatever else you wanted. In my case I am building a searchable database off an `Entry` object, so if the user has typed in a string that doesn't exist in the database, it is giving the user a plain language error.