# Two things: 1) Printing errors/tracebacks/exceptions to GUI and 2) The best way to utilize a script within a script

Tags: python, user-interface, error-handling, tkinter

I am asking these questions together because I feel like they go together. The way to do one effects how I have to do the other. I am a computer science/programming/python novice.

I have a very long, complicated script that doesn't contain any user-defined functions.  It takes the inputs and manipulates them to form an output.  I have built a GUI with Tkinter for the user to input data.  I want to run my script within my GUI mainloop and have the script print status updates and errors to the GUI.

**Printing errors to GUI**: I have searched and searched for a possible solution but I have not managed to crack this.

[Using a subprocess](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/665566/redirect-command-line-results-to-a-tkinter-gui) looked the most promising, but I believe the subprocess must be a .exe file in order for that to work.  I have only a Python script and do not know how to convert something into an executable (but I will need to learn soon anyway).  As for the second response on that page with the sys module, I just don't understand what's going on in the "run_script" function to apply it to my own GUI.

[There's this "show error" solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6666882/tkinter-python-catching-exceptions) but I am not sure I really understand this, either.  Is this saying that I need to put `Try...Except...` on all of the functions in my subscript and have it spit back a message box?  Yick.  I would really much prefer the exception get printed like it does in the command result/IDE and exit the command.  Would the traceback solution on that page be a one-and-done sort of thing that I state once in my GUI and have it work for all functions in the GUI?  Or would I have to call that show_error function every time I carry out a computation?

**Incorporating the subscript**:  I realized that the manner in which I incorporate the subscript will impact how the messages are printed in the GUI.  I have a bunch of print statements in my subscript (`print "Loading modules..."`) to let the user know the program is running. Before moving on, here is an example of the code I am working with.

Here is a shortened version of my GUI code:

```
import Tkinter

###____________Widgets__________________###
class InputBox(Tkinter.Tk):
    def __init__(self,parent):
        Tkinter.Tk.__init__(self, parent)
        self.parent = parent
        self.initialize()

    def initialize(self):
        # Frame
        self.OK = Tkinter.Frame(self, padx=3, pady=3)
        self.OK.grid(column=2, row=2, columnspan=3, sticky="EW")

        self.printFrame = Tkinter.LabelFrame(self, borderwidth=3, relief="ridge", padx=3, pady=3, text="Results")
        self.printFrame.grid(column=0, row=3, columnspan=4, sticky="EW")

        # Approval
        self.OKbutton = Tkinter.Button(self.OK, text=u"OK", command=self.OKgo, anchor="e")
        self.OKbutton.pack(side="right")

        self.view = Tkinter.Text(self.printFrame)
        self.view.grid(column=0, row=0, columnspan=3, sticky="EW")
        self.scroll = Tkinter.Scrollbar(self.printFrame, orient=Tkinter.VERTICAL)
        self.scroll.config(command=self.view.yview)
        self.view.config(yscrollcommand=self.scroll.set)
        self.scroll.grid(column=4, row=0, sticky="SN")

    def OKgo(self):
        # Load Inputs
        DEMin = self.demEntryVar.get()
        WTin = self.wtEntryVar.get()
        soil = self.soilEntryVar.get()
```

Here's a very small piece of my "subscript":

```
# Convert soils shapefile to raster and assign integer values to HSG.
# A=1, B=2, C=3, 4=D and dual groups A/D=14, B/D=24, C/D=34
# "---" is treated as a D soil
import arcpy
print("Converting dual group soils to single groups...")
SoilUnclass = arcpy.PolygonToRaster_conversion(soil, "HSG", ScratchPath + r"\SoilUnclass", "MAXIMUM_COMBINED_AREA")
SoilClass = arcpy.sa.Reclassify(SoilUnclass, "HSG", arcpy.sa.RemapValue([["A", 1],
                       ["B", 2],
                       ["C", 3],
                       ["D", 4],
                       ["A/D", 14],
                       ["B/D", 24],
                       ["C/D", 34],
                       ["---", 4]]), "NODATA")
SoilClass.save(ScratchPath + r"\HSGras")
```

If I paste the subscript code directly into the `OKgo` function, I can get it to print to the Text widget by changing all the print statements to `self.view.insert("end", "Converting soils... \n")`.  As I understand it, pasting my whole subscript into the `OKgo` function is undesirable because it freezes the GUI and generally is very long.  The subscript can take a substantial amount of time to run so this isn't preferred.

I can also break my subscript into numerous user-defined functions and call them individually within the `OKgo` function with something like

```
import subscript as ss
ss.soilconvert(soil)
```

This would be much cleaner and easier for me to diagnose and do the `Try...Except...` thing with even thought it freezes the GUI.  The outputs from one function are needed as inputs for the next function, however, and I don't know how to call those back.  I also do not know how I would turn the `print` statements into something that could be read into the Text widget.

I saw some stuff about `execfile` too, but I feel like that's even harder to get the output into the Text widget with.  :/  I don't know any programming conventions or know what would be easier to debug/update.  I need some direction, please.  Thanks.

EDIT:

I created a single-thread version using import statments and a `multiprocessing` version.  I did something like this: [Python multiprocessing redirect stdout of a child process to a Tkinter Text](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23947281/python-multiprocessing-redirect-stdout-of-a-child-process-to-a-tkinter-text) to trap `stdout` and print it to the GUI.  I am still trying to get the exceptions to work.  Redirecting `sys.stderr` in the same way I redirected `sys.stdout` is not working but I have yet to try to `sys.excepthook` thing.

Answer (score 0):

You can trap all exceptions and display them using `sys.excepthook`: just
replace it with your own function that would open an message box with
the error traceback and exit, if you want:

```
import sys, traceback
def my_except_hook(type, value, traceback):
    exception_string = "".join(traceback.format_exception(type, value, traceback)) 
    # do whatever you want from here
    print exception_string
sys.excepthook = my_except_hook
```

About starting a subscript from a Python script: the `execfile` solution
can do, you can redirect stdout and stderr by replacing default
`sys.stdout` and `sys.stderr`, however starting a subprocess using the
`subprocess` module may be more appropriate to avoid corruption of the
main Python script.

Comment: So if I use `execfile`, there's a chance for my subscript to become corrupted?   With `subprocess`, my file needs to be an executable; I want to use it as a Python script.  I hear I can use `multiprocess` to use it as a .py rather than a .exe ... I am still trying to understand the `multiprocess` module, though.  It looks like I need or should pass variables from my main process to the subprocess using a queue/pipe?  I am most concerned about corrupting my scripts and inputs; I want to minimize/zero the chance of corruption of any part of my scripts, even if the implementation is clunky.

Comment: Go with the `subprocess` solution, the executable can be Python itself I don't see the problem ; you have the executable path in `sys.executable` so you can start a subprocess with a command line with `sys.executable` as first argument and your Python script as second argument...

Comment: Kind of.  I solved them but then ran into a new problem so I'm back to square 1.  I couldn't get the excepthook solution to work. :\  I am trying to implement routing sys.stdout/stderr in a threadsafe way so the GUI will update.