# Show error message box if, literally, any error occurs in a code

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

I want to show the error message box pop up if anything goes wrong in the input. For example, in this code, if a number is entered, it will work. But if anything else is entered, the error will occur. In this example, we could specify that if the input is not a number, we show an error message box. But in other codes, there may be a lot of variables. Can we just take the whole code and show the error message box if an error occurs in any part of the code?

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import *

window = tk.Tk()

canvas = tk.Canvas(window,width=980, height=580, highlightthickness=0)
canvas.pack()

def open_window(pll):
    global g
    g = pll*pll

    show_button = tk.Button(canvas, text='Show square of number', command=lambda:show_result())
    canvas.create_window(185, 30, window=show_button, anchor=tk.NW)

def show_result():


    gg=str(g)
    l1 = tk.Label(canvas, text=gg)
    canvas.create_window(200,60, window=l1, anchor=tk.NW)




l0 = tk.Label(canvas, text="Enter Number")
canvas.create_window(3,5, window=l0, anchor=tk.NW)

PLz = tk.DoubleVar()
entry_PLz = tk.Entry(canvas, textvariable=PLz)
entry_PLz.config({"background": "gainsboro"})
canvas.create_window(250,15, window=entry_PLz)

submit_button = tk.Button(canvas, text="Process", command=lambda: open_window(PLz.get()))
canvas.create_window(100, 30, window=submit_button, anchor=tk.NW)

window.title('Try')
window.mainloop()
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Handling exception in python tkinter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15246523/handling-exception-in-python-tkinter)

Comment: You could a `try/except` statement and then just `except BaseException as e:` then you can use `e` for your message. The `BaseException` is a catch all. That said you could force validation on you entry field so the user cannot input anything except for a number value.