# "SyntaxError: non-keyword arg after keyword arg" when trying to bind a function to a button in tkinter

Tags: python, lambda, tkinter

I am trying to bind a button press to a function in Tkinter when I run the following line of code

```
get = Button(root, lambda: ChangeColour(boxes[1][2], boxes[5][2], 
             main)).pack(fill = BOTH)
```

I get the following error

SyntaxError: non-keyword arg after keyword arg

Am I missing something, should I be binding the function differently?

EDIT: 
Stack trace below

```
File "C:/Users/07725172499/Documents/a.py", line 151
  relief=RIDGE, lambda: ChangeColour(boxes[1][2], boxes[5][2], main)).pack(fill = BOTH)
                                  ^
SyntaxError: non-keyword arg after keyword arg
```

Process finished with exit code 1

Comment: I don't see a problem. Can you post a full stack trace?

Comment: What is a full stack trace and how do I get it

Comment: When you got `SyntaxError: non-keyword arg after keyword arg` was it inside a bunch of text showing what lines were being evaluated? That's what we need.

Comment: This may help for catching exceptions... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32189391/handle-uncaught-exceptions-with-tkinter. Or just wrap that one thing in a try/except and do `traceback.print_exc()1.

Comment: Added the stack trace

Comment: Try `command=lambda:`

Comment: The stack trace shows you executing a different line than what you posted.... notice no `relief=RIDGE`, That's one of the reasons why the trace is important to validate an error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error `SyntaxError: non-keyword arg after keyword arg` occurs when you break the Python requirement that arguments can be given in a mixture of positional order and keyword=value pairs but once a keyword is provided, you cannot subsequently within that function call use positional order. For example, if a function definition begins with

```
def foo(first, second, third):
```

then calling the function with

```
foo(1, 2, 3)
```

is ok and

```
foo(1, 2, third=3)
```

is ok but

```
foo(1, second=2, 3)
```

is not ok.

From your traceback, it looks like you provided a value for the `relief` parameter by keyword, so you need to provide the function to bind by keyword. Use `command=lamda:` as the argument. However, I suspect that your call to `ChangeColor` is returning a value that is not a function and therefore does not match the expected type for the command argument of `Button`.

To figure out why your code is breaking this syntax requirement, I recommend breaking up the line of code so that you can identify whether it is the call to `ChangeColor`, `pack` or `Button` that is causing the problem. To make your code easier to debug, put each function call on its own line:

```
bound_function = ChangeColour(boxes[1][2], boxes[5][2], main)
my_button = Button(root, bound_function)
get = my_button.pack(fill=BOTH)
```