# How to create a message box when errors occured in tkinter

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter, messagebox

it is a little bit difficult to explain. I would like a message box to prompt anytime an error occured. For example I have an user interface which allows the user to select options from combobox and create a file depending on the choice. I would like to prompt a messagebox for example when a combobox is not completed.

To simplify, when an error occured and is printed on the python terminal, I want a messagebox to pop-up and tell the user "you do something wrong". Is there any way to do that ? Because I can't really find tutorials on it.

Hope this is clear enough to understand.

Comment: There are `try:` and `except:` blocks you can use. In your exception you can define instructions how the exception is handled, including to throw out a messegebox.

Comment: This [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4770993/how-can-i-make-silent-exceptions-louder-in-tkinter) may help.  Although it is for Python 2, but the logic works on Python 3 as well.