# Try exception in tkinter by using messagebox

Tags: python, tkinter, exception, messagebox

I want to try exception in tkinter. If I do not input anything into entry, it will raise ValueError and the messagebox will pop up. However, when I run my code, it indeed can catch exception, but no messagebox pops up. Can anyone tells me reason and how to correct it? Thank you.

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import messagebox
try:

    root = Tk()
    
    def function():
        if not entry_test.get():
            raise ValueError
        Label(root, text = entry_test.get()).grid()
    
    
    entry_test = Entry(root)
    entry_test.grid()
    
    button_click = Button(root, text ="click to test", command= function)
    button_click.grid()
    
    root.mainloop()

except ValueError:
    message.showwarning("ENTRY ERROR", "please input somthing in entry")
```

Comment: Do the answers to this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4770993/how-can-i-make-silent-exceptions-louder-in-tkinter) help at all?

Comment: It is really helpful, thank you.