# How to know if an error has occurred in a tkinter app without a console?

Tags: python, tkinter, console

I am working on tkinter project, which the user can't see the console. Is there a way the user can know an error has occurred in the program with out seeing the console.

Comment: You can replace the function "sys.excepthook" by your code which can show a window or write to a log file if an error occurs.

Comment: @MichaelButscher: `sys.excepthook` won't always work depending on when the exception occurs. For example, when one happens in a callback function if won't be called.

Comment: @Nahom: Note the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71638411/355230) I just posted to the duplicate question.

Answer (score 0):

```
messagebox.showerror()
```

You can use this code for showing error.

Comment: The trick is getting something to call that when an exception occurs…

Answer (score 0):

You can add `try except` statement from the beginning to end of your program, and in `except` you can use `messagebox.showerror` to show error.

And for catching the Tkinter error check this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4771200/16187613)

But if you want to catch Python errors too for example if index out of range error occur while running a for loop you use

```
# Note import files before the try statement

from tkinter import *
from tkinter import messagebox 
import sys,traceback
def show_error(slef, *args):
    err = traceback.format_exception(*args)
    messagebox.showerror('Exception',err)
try:
    root=Tk()
    
    Tk.report_callback_exception = show_error
    exec(input()) # Just used to throw error
    a=Button(text='s',command=lambda: print(8/0)) # Just used to throw error
    a.pack()
    root.mainloop()
except BaseException as e:
    messagebox.showerror('Exception',e)
```

Comment: Surprisingly, this doesn't work (try it).

Comment: @martineau , yeah that was because of wrong name. i have fixed it, thanks for pointing out.

Comment: No, that was not the reason why.

Comment: @martineau , oh for me its working, i have tried it by dividing interger by 0

Comment: Same here, but it doesn't work for me. In my code a `Button` callback function divides by 0.

Comment: @martineau , that question is the exact answer, so should i delete this answer?

Comment: Doesn't really matter one way or another now — so that's totally up to you. IMO it could be useful for someone to see your wrong answer and these comments. The subtlety is that exceptions in tkinter callbacks aren't affected by a `try` / `except` at a higher level (as currently shown in your answer).